# find with how many digits array is filled?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, count

Let's say I have array of bytes

```
byte[] arr = new byte[16];
```

and I filled only 10 of those 16 bytes

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
arr[2] = 2;
arr[3] = 3;
arr[4] = 4;
arr[5] = 5;
arr[6] = 6;
arr[7] = 7;
arr[8] = 8;
arr[9] = 9;
arr[10] = 1;
```

the problem is that user can input up to 10 digits, and the last digit could be 0

How can I find how many digits my array holds, since arr.Length and arr.Count() will give 16 but I need to know that it's 10?

Comment: What if you filled one of the array elements with a 0? Is that possible? If so, how would you anticipate differentiating between that and it just being 0 by default? What's the use case here?

Comment: You may want to have a look at [Using Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx).

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to vote down all the answers that seem to imply that a value of 0 is different to any other value. It's just daft (and dangerous) to program in this fashion and it should not be encouraged.

Comment: that's my main question how to find out if the last digit was filled with 0 or if it's 0 by default

Comment: Just incase the array index is significant as well that the value it's set to and `arr[1]` is skipped deliberately, Then `Dictionary<int, byte>` might be a better replacement than list.

Comment: @Stanislav, to be clear, is this a homework problem or something? Perhaps with the text "allow a user to enter and store [up to 10 or 16] values and enter 0 when he is finished, then redisplay all of the values entered?" Your recent edit simply varies widely with the originally stated question.

Comment: it's not homework... just very tricky thing...

Comment: @Stanislav - I just updated my answer

Answer (score 7):

I think you'd be better off using a generic [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx). Then you can use the `Count` property to get the correct number of items.

```
List<byte> arr = new List<byte>();

arr.Add(1);
arr.Add(2);
arr.Add(3);
arr.Add(4);
arr.Add(5);

int count = arr.Count; // returns 5;
byte[] myArray = arr.ToArray(); // returns byte array
```

**UPDATE**

If an array is your only option and you cannot switch to a `List<T>` then you are out of luck. The problem is, by default, C# will initialize each byte in the array to `0`. So as soon as the compiler gets to the `new byte[16];` initialization, the entire byte array is filled with 0's. Once this happens, there is no way to know if the 0 is the default value or if its a valid value. If there is a number between 0 and 255 that you 100% know will not be used, you could initialize the array with that number and get a count of each element != to that number.

Another thing you can do though is you can just initialize the array to one byte (e.g. `new byte[1]`) and each time you need more elements, [resize the array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) an additional byte. Then you can use the standard `Length` property to see how many are filled.

Comment: This is the only answer that encourages the user to go to the source of the problem rather than patching a broken concept. +1

Comment: Just so that it matches the question that tiny bit closer you could set the initial capacity of the list.

Comment: @JamesB The fact that he's asking this question means that he doesn't know the number of items the collection will have in advance, so it's probably best to *not* set the capacity.

Comment: The question skips `arr[1]`. If that is meaningful, the problem has not been solved (and, of course, it would help if the problem were better described).

Comment: @AnthonyPegram - I think him skipping `arr[1]` was just a typo and not intentional, though it does bring up a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Well if `"0"` means the item isn't filled (which means you can't use `0` as a valid entry) you could use:

```
int numFilled = arr.Count(b => b != 0);
```

Otherwise you're going to have to use a "magic" number (e.g. `255`) to indicate an "unused" item.

Either way it's not foolproof.  If there's not a reason to use a fixed-length array then I'd suggest using a different structure like `List<byte>` which can be filled dynamically and easily *converted* to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = arr.Where(item => item != 0).Count();
```

Or

```
int count = arr.Count(item => item != 0);
```

[EDIT] As Jon Skeet says above, this assumes that you did not fill any of the entries with 0.